# Implementation a type of Quicksort

Tags: java, recursion, quicksort, partitioning, implementation

i have a code of standart quicksort implementation in java but i need to implement a quicksort algorithm in  a youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ywWBy6J5gz8

i know how to implement standart quicksort but it just divide the algorithm two sides;lower than pivot and bigger than pivot

```
static int partition(int []arr, int low,
                                int high)
{
    int pivot = arr[high];
     
    
    int i = (low - 1);
 
    for (int j = low; j <= high- 1; j++)
    {
       
        if (arr[j] <= pivot)
        {
            i++; 
            Swap(arr, i, j);
        }
    }
    Swap(arr, i + 1, high);
    return (i + 1);
}
 
static void quickSort(int []arr, int low,
                                 int high)
{
    if (low < high)
    {
        
        int pi = partition(arr, low, high);
 
        
        quickSort(arr, low, pi - 1);
        quickSort(arr, pi + 1, high);
    }
}
```

i implemented the hoare's partition for divide the array two parts but in the video dividing array two parts is not enough

the algorithm in the video find the correct location of the pivot divide the array in two,find the correct location of the new pivots divide the array in two until after the partitions there is one element in each part

it's much slower than standart quicksort but i don't understand how to implement it can you guys help me to implement it?

Answer (score -1):

```
public class QuickSort_Impl {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] unsortedArray = {12, 3, 45, 23, 6, -4, -6, 10, 1, 8};

        quickSort(unsortedArray, 0, unsortedArray.length);

        // Print Sorted Array
        for (int i : unsortedArray)
            System.out.print(i+ " ");

    }

    static void quickSort(int[] arg, int startIndex, int endIndex)
    {
        // Base Case
        if (endIndex - startIndex < 2)   // We can't partition any further
           return;

        // Find the pivot index to get the picot value for comparison
        int pivotIndex = getPivotIndex(arg, startIndex, endIndex);
        // Use the pivot to sort
        quickSort(arg, startIndex, pivotIndex); // For Left Partition of the Array
        quickSort(arg, pivotIndex + 1, endIndex); // For Right Partition of the array
    }

    private static int getPivotIndex(int[] arg, int startIndex, int endIndex)
    {
        int pivotVal = arg[startIndex]; // Our Pivot Value is chosen to be the 1st element in the arg[]
        int i = startIndex;
        int j = endIndex;

        // Traverse from left to right and Right to Left and compare each element with the pivot
        while (i < j)
        {
            // Right Traverse
            while (i < j && (arg[--j] >= pivotVal)); // Do nothing because the element is on the right-side of the pivot
            // If there is an element smaller than the pivot on the right-side of the pivot, move it to left-side
            if (i < j)
                arg[i] = arg[j];

            // Left Traverse
            while (i < j && (arg[++i] <= pivotVal)); // Do nothing because the element is on the left-side of the pivot
            // If there is an element greater than the pivot on the left-side of the pivot, move it to the right-side
            if (i < j)
                arg[j] = arg[i];

        }//End Outer while

        // Move pivot to the right-side of the sorted array/sub-array
        arg[j] = pivotVal;
        // Return the index of the pivot
        return j;
    }
}
```

Checkout the sample in my repo, hope it helps
[Sorting Sample](https://github.com/torryola/AlgorithmsAndDataStructures-Repo/tree/master/src/net/torrypubrepo/Algorithms/Sorting/QuickSort)

Comment: thanks for the help i think that's what i want to implement

Comment: @Blastfurnace - thanks for constructive comment. It's my repo and just thought it's quicker. Sample is now included in the answer

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.